On Yom Tov, if you didn't say Kiddush at night, what should you now say before lunch?
This question discusses the case of someone who missed saying Kiddush on Friday night. The answer says to say the nighttime Kiddush the next day; see there for details.
I'm interested in the analogous case of missing Kiddush on Yom Tov night. The laws of Yom Tov are not always identical to those of Shabbat. Please tell us if the above rule applies to Yom Tov as well, or if there is some relevant distinction.
Please cite your sources.
